# kubernetes : Service shared between multiple namespaces

Tags: kubernetes

I'm  searching for the answer but i didn't find it anywhere.
Is it possible to share a service between multiple namespaces ?

For instance, if i have 2 namespaces (let's say 'qa' and 'dev'), is it possible to use the same database server ?
The database server would be preferably managed by kubernetes too.

I've read this issue : https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/1244
But it's not directly related to kubernetes.

Regards,
Smana

Answer (score 13):

Services are accessible from all namespaces as long as you address them using both the name and the namespace.

For example, if you have a service named `db` in namespace `dev`, you can access it using the DNS name `db`. While this won't work from `qa`, you can access it from both `qa` and `dev` if you instead use the DNS name `db.dev` (`<service>.<namespace>`), in order to clarify which namespace should be searched for the service.

Comment: Thanks Alex, i'll try that

Comment: for me that does not work. is there some reference in the docs about this?

Comment: It's likely that the cluster you're using has some security policies set up, such as network policies (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/), that prevent the communication. Communicating across namespaces like this still works in plain vanilla clusters. If you have a cluster admin of some sort, I'd ask them what's up.